# Vagrant detach .vdi file before destroy or just don't remove it

Tags: vagrant

In Vagrantfile I attach manually created `db.vdi` disk:

```
vb.customize [
  'storageattach', :id, 
  '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', 
  '--port', 1, '--device', 0, 
  '--type', 'hdd', 
  '--medium', 'db.vdi'
]
```

It works great but when I destroy vagrant box this file is removed. I tried to fix that fix vagrant triggers. `before :destroy` `before :halt` doesn't work, I get an error that drive is not hotpluggable.  `after :halt`doesn't work at all:

```
config.trigger.after :halt do
  run "VBoxManage storageattach '#{@machine.id}'" +
    " --storagectl 'SATA Controller' --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"
end
```

What I am trying to do is that when I run `vagrant destroy` I want to gracefully halt machine, deattach vdi file so vagrant will not remove it, destroy everything else.

Is it possible?

---

Edit:

It looks it's possible to do it with plugin hooks https://github.com/kusnier/vagrant-persistent-storage/blob/master/lib/vagrant-persistent-storage/plugin.rb - see references to `Action.detach_storage` but I have no idea how to use it within Vagrantfile

---

See @FrédéricHenri - detach is triggered too soon:

```
==> default: Running triggers before destroy...
==> default: dettach drive
==> !!! TOO SOON !!!
==> default: Executing command "VBoxManage storageattach d0132b78-11ea-41cf-b003-dac15536520c --storagectl SATAController --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"...
==> default: Command execution finished.
    default: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y

==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> !!! THIS IS WHERE I SHOULD DETACH THE DRIVE !!!
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're correct as if you look the example plugin, they do hook after halt command and before destroy.

## getting the machine Id

the issue is with the way you're running the command `run "VBoxManage storageattach '#{@machine.id}'" ..` will return an empty `machine.id`; vagrant in the Vagrantfile script does not know about the machine that it is building, so you get an error that it cannot find a reference VM with an empty ID/Name and the command cannot be executed successfully.

What you need is to get the VirtualBox VM Id so you can pass it to the command; this Id is saved in the file `.vagrant/machines/<name>/<provider>/id`, assuming you did not set a specific name for your VM, it will be:

## working with *before destroy* trigger

```
  config.trigger.before :destroy do
    info "dettach drive"
    machineId = File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id")
    run "VBoxManage storageattach '#{machineId}'" +
      " --storagectl 'SATA Controller' --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"
  end
```

## hotpluggable error when ejecting the drive while destroying the VM

For the *hotpluggable* pat, you need to make sure the file is indeed hot pluggable when attached so it can be unplugged while the VM is still running (that is before destroying)

You can make this config from your Vagrantfile when attaching the hard drive

```
vb.customize [
  'storageattach', :id, 
  '--storagectl', 'SATAController', 
  '--port', 1, '--device', 0, 
  '--type', 'hdd', 
  '--medium', 'db.vdi',
  '--hotpluggable', 'on'
]
```

When running a `destroy` command for this VM, you get

```
fhenri:~/project/vagrant/drive$ vagrant destroy
==> default: Running triggers before destroy...
==> default: dettach drive
==> default: Executing command "VBoxManage storageattach d0132b78-11ea-41cf-b003-dac15536520c --storagectl SATAController --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"...
==> default: Command execution finished.
    default: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y

==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
```

so you can clearly see the command is executed correctly and drive is dettached,  I can see the drive is still on my local hard drive, then I can answer yes to destroy the VM files

## working with *after halt* trigger

On my side, it just works as fine with the *after halt* trigger hook too:

from Vagrantfile

```
  config.trigger.after :halt do
    info "dettach drive"
    machineId = File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id")
    run "VBoxManage storageattach '#{machineId}'" +
      " --storagectl 'SATAController' --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"
  end
```

will run

```
fhenri:~/project/vagrant/drive$ vagrant halt
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Running triggers after halt...
==> default: dettach drive
==> default: Executing command "VBoxManage storageattach 74274ab6-173e-4934-9864-33e09be26214 --storagectl SATAController --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"...
==> default: Command execution finished.
```

The remaining issue for you is to make sure not to call *destroy* in this case as destroy does not halt the VM, it just destroy it so it does not call the halt command and bypass the halt trigger, you could work with an additional detroy plugin but it will mean the hot pluggable thing you do not want

## Prevent destroy if drive is attached

You can check the numbers of drive attached on device by checking `vboxmanage showvminfo <uuid>` and look the value for *storagecontrollerportcount0*

You can translate that in your before destroy trigger

```
  config.trigger.before :destroy do
    vm_info = `vboxmanage showvminfo #{@machine.id} --machinereadable | grep storagecontrollerportcount0`
    value = Integer(vm_info.split("=")[1].gsub('"','').chomp())
    raise Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError.new, "drive attached - cannot be destroyed" if value > 1
  end
```

It will raise an error if you have more than 1 drive attached and will not continue the execution of destroy command

Comment: I am 100% sure that with vagrant-triggers plugin `'#{@machine.id}'` is not empty, I echoed command before trying it and machine ID is not empty and command is right. [See what plugin author says](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers/issues/29). The issue is **I need to detach drive between final halt and destroy**.

Comment: ok, maybe the plugin exposed the machine object - before destroy is the step you want, if you run this, it will detach your drive before it is destroyed with the VM files so the file will remain on drive

Comment: The thing is I don't want to make it hot pluggable! I want halt machine, detach, and destroy while running `vagrant destroy`. Vagrant is trying to detach drive on working VM, hot unplugging drive may cause data loss...  http://i.imgur.com/vBSvm3O.png

Comment: "before destroy is the step you want" no, `config.trigger.before :destroy do` is triggered while machine is still running you can see it even on your answer "Executing command VBoxManage storageattach " then "Forcing shutdown of VM..."

Comment: ok you want after halt, it works fine, but dont call detroy then, destroy does not halt the VM, so it bypass the halt trigger, and will delete your drive (unless you have a trigger for destroy too, but to make this one working you need the hot pluggable feature)

Comment: hmm i can follow the halt then destroy method. can you help me how to prevent machine being destroyed if any drive is attached?

Comment: adding an example .. you need to execute the command `vboxmanage showvminfo #{@machine.id} --machinereadable | grep storagecontrollerportcount0` I rely on grep, if you do not run a *nix system (macos works fine) you would need to get the whole output of showvminfo and loop through each line until you get the one starting with `storagecontrollerportcount0`

Comment: Thanks for great help I really appreciate. I awarded you a bounty but not accepted because it really doesn't answer "Vagrant detach .vdi file before destroy or just don't remove it" so maybe someone else can help. Anyways it looks its not possible with custom plugin but halt/prevent destroy will do job as workaround

Comment: I also moved whole vagrant instance to subdirectory and created custom vagrant script that will redirect everything to vagrant except destroy where it will execute `vagrant halt && vagrant destroy`

Comment: yep. the other workaround is to use hotpluggable drive, it should work fine (not sure what you meant in context of virtualization, you dont really accidentaly remove a drive unless you really write a command for it) ; you can have custom script or just write an alias so it will run `vagrant halt && vagrant destroy` in the before trigger you can check the state of the VM and make sure its not running otherwise you dont run it

Comment: i don't want to use hotpluggable option because hot unplugging drive while db service is running may cause data corruption

Answer (score 1):

I found this plugin https://github.com/kusnier/vagrant-persistent-storage

it looks like what I needed but unfortunately there is option only for one disk

Comment: seems you're not the only requesting for this .. https://github.com/kusnier/vagrant-persistent-storage/issues/61

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yeah. i don't even need whole plugin, i can repartition and create disks by myself, i just want to dettach it between final halt and destroy

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it with vagrant 2.1.1 (2.1.2 has broken trigger), on windows7 host, with fedora guest (with oddly an IDE controller).

So my solution, daft maybe as it is, is the following:

```
config.trigger.after :halt do |x| 
machID = "./.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id"
if File.file?(machID)
    machineID = File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id")
end
if defined?(machineID)
    x.run = {inline: "VBoxManage storageattach '#{machineID}' 
    --storagectl 'IDE' --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none"}
end



config.trigger.before :destroy do |x|
x.name = "Halting machine"
x.run = {inline: "vagrant halt default"}
end
```

So basically, when you call trigger destroy 'before', it first halts the machine (for the trigger after 'halt'), detaches the disk, then calls destroy. It works on both running machines and halted ones. So sort of persistent disk.

P.S. It might need some safeguards around it all